# Polynomial interpolation of $f(x)=-x^2/2+|x|$

Tags: polynomials, self-learning, interpolation

I have a function, for example $f(x)=\frac{-x^2}{2}+|x|$,  which is divided on $[-1,0)$ and $[0,1]$. How do we interpolate this function with a polynomial $p$ in the maximum degree 4 with $p'(x_0)=f'(x_0)$ and $p'(x_2)=f'(x_2)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to interpolate through the points $-1$, $0$ and $1$ also. You need to satisfy the system
\begin{align*}
p\left(-1\right) & =f\left(-1\right)\\
p\left(0\right) & =f\left(0\right)\\
p\left(1\right) & =f\left(1\right)\\
p^{\prime}\left(0\right) & =f^{\prime}\left(0\right)\\
p^{\prime}\left(1\right) & =f^{\prime}\left(1\right).
\end{align*}
Now, take
$$
p\left(x\right)\equiv ax^{4}+bx^{3}+cx^{2}+dx+e
$$
and note that the derivative is
$$
p^{\prime}\left(x\right)=4ax^{3}+3bx^{2}+2cx+d.
$$
You can plug these into the system above and solve the corresponding equations for $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ and $e$.

Comment: Oh yes,thank you!

Comment: You can press the checkmark to accept my answer if you are satisfied with it.

Comment: In this polynomal interpolation how could we find the error??

Comment: The error at $x$ is $\left|f\left(x\right) - p\left(x\right)\right|$. There may be other definitions of error that may be more pertinent to your application.